# How to retrieve git pull history

Tags: git

Whenever I git pulled from remote repo into my local repo, did Git store the information of **WHEN** I pull? Can I see the log of pulls that I did in my local repo?

Comment: [reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837982/7976758)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try and see the content of your [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)... but that will be limited in time (90 days by default)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\git
> git reflog --date=iso|grep pull
3ec7d702a HEAD@{2017-09-10 17:42:57 +0200}: pull --no-commit origin master: Fast-forward
b3622a4ee HEAD@{2017-08-12 10:36:08 +0200}: pull: Fast-forward
97e2ff464 HEAD@{2017-06-17 18:43:28 +0200}: pull: Fast-forward
8d1b10321 HEAD@{2017-06-08 20:36:08 +0200}: pull: Fast-forward
10c78a162 HEAD@{2017-05-21 21:22:58 +0200}: pull: Fast-forward
b06d36431 HEAD@{2017-05-14 07:36:49 +0200}: pull: checkout b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c
1d1bdafd6 HEAD@{2016-12-22 00:36:52 +0100}: pull --no-commit origin master: checkout 1d1bdafd64266e5ee3bd46c6965228f32e4022ea
3ab228137 HEAD@{2016-11-12 08:25:02 +0100}: pull: checkout 3ab228137f980ff72dbdf5064a877d07bec76df9
2632c897f HEAD@{2016-08-20 21:52:51 +0200}: pull: checkout 2632c897f74b1cc9b5533f467da459b9ec725538
2376d3178 HEAD@{2016-08-13 09:19:54 +0200}: pull: checkout 2376d31787760af598db23bb3982a57419854e5c
f8f7adce9 HEAD@{2016-07-31 13:34:44 +0200}: pull: checkout f8f7adce9fc50a11a764d57815602dcb818d1816
ab7797dbe HEAD@{2016-06-22 11:53:20 +0200}: pull: checkout ab7797dbe95fff38d9265869ea367020046db118
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC . reflog is populating from the HEAD log in .git/log it seems. Since I noticed the time differs from the commit time, I assume this is the pull time that I have been looking for.

Comment: This really help me to see when did we pull from remote. Great question and great answer

Comment: For Windows users: use `findstr` instead of `grep`.

Comment: @Venryx I usually add to my `%PATH%` the `usr/bin` folder of Git for Windows (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672939/6309): that means I get 200+ linux commands, including a `grep.exe`